# nutch replace parsed content before indexing

Tags: nutch

I am using nutch 1.15. I want to replace some string of the parsed content before getting indexed.

Is there a way to write the regexp and replace the contents?

Example:

```
Content : "This is the crawled page"

I want to replace "page" with string "content"
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to do the replacement in the content (parsed text). You can write a custom `IndexFilter` similar to https://github.com/apache/nutch/tree/master/src/plugin/index-replace that manipulates the data before sending it to your storage.

The previous plugin works only on the metadata fields, but should provide a good overview on how to build your own.

There is also something similar that you can do on the Solr side, for instance take a look at this [blog post](http://blog.coviam.com/solr-internals-modifying-solr-documents-before-indexing/)